# How to grant User Points to viewing user when user has viewed content?

Tags: rules, userpoints

Can anyone provide me with a simple rule that adds 1 user point to a user when this user has viewed an entity of "Article" (for example)?

I have enabled the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module and the "Userpoints rules" integration module. But I can't find a way to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, worth to be considered as a great question for a Drupal site building exam!

Have a look at this rule:

```
{ "grant_user_points_after_content_view" : {
    "LABEL" : "Grant user points after content view",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_view--article" : { "bundle" : "article" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "points" : "1",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "node" ],
          "description" : "View of node with id \u0022[node:nid]\u0022 and title \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "NodeViewed",
          "reference" : "Viewing of [node:content-type] \u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E\/node\/[node:nid]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some details about this rule, which you should be able to import in your own site if you have the Rules UI, and [Userpoints Rules](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/userpoints/tree/userpoints_rules.info) (a sub-module of [Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints)), enabled and after you enable the rule also:

- Rules Event: a Node of content "Article" is viewed (adapt the machine name of the used content type to any type that fits).
- Rules Condition: user is authenticated (to be able to grant user points).
- Rules Action: grant 1 point to the user viewing the article. And use some of the available tokens to add some more details to the actual User Points transaction (description, operation, reference) ... just for fun.

Easy, no? Sorry you had to wait for 2 years ...

PS: The previous answer is not really an answer to the question here I think.

Comment: Hello Pierre,
Thanks for this but I cannot find the Userpoints Rules. That module does not seem to exist. Can you check your link please. Even after 2 years, still good! Ta!

Comment: Awesome Pierre! It works! I gotta dig deeper into all the userpoint rules settings to get to the nitty-gritty! THANK YOU AGAIN!

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't aware of clicking the 'tick'. Here you go ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [variable module](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable), then you can do it.

Please follow the steps:

1. Provide a new variable (**text type!**), called **Number**, with the
   necessary PHP code (wrapped with `<?php ... ?>`). One can then use
   earlier calculated results like `$mynumber`.
2. Convert **Number** to an integer, called **Points**.
3. Grant **Points** to the user.

Hope this may help. Thank you.

Comment: I think the key thing is that the question asker wants to assign user points. This answer doesn't really address that.

Comment: @rooby: And now I have completely updated the answer. Please have a try. Thank you.

Comment: Oops, that goes a bit beyond my knowledge but I'll try it. Thanks.