# Is there way for create custom "add userpoints transaction" form

Tags: 7, views, userpoints

Good day to everyone!

I have view which show user list, current userpoints, and email. I want set some link, which will lead to add transaction form where name will already fill. Is there way to add userpoints transaction for specific user except standard form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step 1

Use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to create a Rules Component, which includes whatever Rules Conditions you might need (if any), and with a Rules Action to **Grant user points**, to the user specified as a parameter for this Rules Component.

For an example of a Rules Action to grant user points, refer to the rule included in the answer to "[How to grant User Points to viewing user when user has viewed content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138132/how-to-grant-user-points-to-viewing-user-when-user-has-viewed-content/220770#220770)".

#### Step 2

Create a view of the group of users for which those fields should be added. Then transform that view into a view that uses [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), and use the technique documented in "[How to use Rules to create a custom bulk operation for a VBO view?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/88)". In doing so, you'll then be able to use the Rules Component from Step 1.

#### Tutorial

To get the idea, have a look at the video about [Using Rules components with VBO](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-components-with-vbo)" which uses a Rules Component with (only) 1 parameter. If you want even more, then also watch the subsequent "[Using Rules components with more than one parameter](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-componens-with-more-than-one-parameter)" video.

Attention: to process like 100.000 entities at once is quite a challenge (memory requirements, etc). Therefor you might want to also watch the video about "[More details about VBO settings](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/more-details-about-vbo-settings)" ... Before you are tempted to use VBO for processing them all at once ...

Comment: you are the greatest answer writer! Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: @NashGC merci for the kudos (and accept), though "greatest" is probaby too much. So "what else" or "what's your next challenge"? PS: can you fix your typo in your title (at the end)?

Comment: I will learn about VBO, it's my nearest challenge and I think it's my last part "technical side" of my project. I hope so)